# Do a lot of statically stored values create scaling problems

Tags: java

This [article](http://www.connorgarvey.com/blog/?p=105) in the end mentions this: "With a lot of statically stored values, your application will not scale well".

I thought that initializing a variable only once and using it across instances is actually efficient as it saves reallocation of memory every time the class is initialized. It seems contradictory to the above statement. I understand that load time may increase as the JVM has to initialize these object at the very outset, but that would be just once.

Can anyone explain what this exactly means or what exactly "a lot" means in the statement?

Comment: It is referring to scaling developers, static variables is akin to the global value anti pattern.  As far as CPU performance goes, static fields and methods are very fast and some performance/low latency specialists use them for exactly that reason.

Comment: @ChrisK This comment would be better as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is referring to scaling developers, static variables is akin to the [global value anti pattern](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad), which can lead to code that is rigid, fragile and difficult to mock/unit test.

As far as CPU performance goes, static fields and methods are very fast because they do not encur the overheads associated with Object Orientated code and some performance/low latency specialists use them for exactly that reason.